# Setting multiple innerHTML with JSON content

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch-api

I have a JSON file with content that I am fetching, then I would like to have div's on my site with a title, description and link. I can get the title working however I can't seem to get the description to load? Any idea why?

JSON

```json
  "portfolio": {
    "item 1": {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Portfolio Item Title | Website ",
      "sdesc": "A website for something",
      "description": "A sample description",
      "published": "2020.08.01",
      "tags": "Web Development",
      "url": "https://example.com"
    }
```

JavaScript

```js
var oneTitle = document.getElementById('1-title');
var oneSDesc = document.getElementById('1-SDesc');
var onelink = document.getElementById('1-link');

fetch(content.json)
    .then((e) => e.json())
    .then((e => {
        oneTitle.innerHTML = e.portfolio["item 1"].title
        oneSDesc.innerHTML = e.portfolio["item 1"].sdesc

    }))
```

HTML

```html
<div class="portfolio-item medium skeleton-box">
  <div class="item-content">
    <h3 id="1-title">Portfolio Item</h3>
    <p id="1-sdesc">Portfolio Item description goes here</p>
    <a href="" id="1-link">Click to learn more.</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your IDs dont match - `1-sdesc` (the actual ID) is different from `1-SDesc` (the one you are looking for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's case sensitive, try `1-sdesc` instead of `SDesc`

Comment: This is working, thanks I thought I had changed that already